# For Loop Overriding Animations

Tags: swift, core-animation

I'm trying to create a new animated line every second on the screen. Each second I do get a new line, however it overrides the old one. I don't know why but it's probably something idiotic I'm overlooking. Here's my code:

```
func repeatThis() {
    for x in 1...10 {
        let time = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), Int64(x) * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            var topLinePatha: UIBezierPath {
                return UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0 + (x * 10), width: 1, height: 10))
            }

            var topLinePathb: UIBezierPath {
                return UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0 + (x * 10), width: Int(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width), height: 10))
            }

            let expAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
            expAnimation.fromValue = topLinePatha.CGPath
            expAnimation.toValue = topLinePathb.CGPath
            expAnimation.duration = self.animationTime
            expAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
            expAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false
            self.addAnimation(expAnimation, forKey: nil)
            print(x)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Edit 1:

Here's an issue I'm having with the animation timing where basically the animations override each other:

```
func repeatThis() {
    var runningPath = UIBezierPath()

    for x in 0...10 {
        delay(Double(x) / 10) {
            let topLineStartPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: x * 10, width: 1, height: 10))
            let topLineEndPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: x * 10, width: Int(self.bounds.width), height: 10))

            let fullStartPath = runningPath.copy() as! UIBezierPath
            fullStartPath.appendPath(topLineStartPath)
            let fullEndPath = runningPath.copy() as! UIBezierPath
            fullEndPath.appendPath(topLineEndPath)

            let expAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
            expAnimation.fromValue = fullStartPath.CGPath
            expAnimation.toValue = fullEndPath.CGPath
            expAnimation.duration = self.animationTime
            expAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
            expAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false
            self.addAnimation(expAnimation, forKey: nil)
            print(x)

            runningPath = fullEndPath
        }
    }
}

func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

Comment: What is `self` in this code?  If you want more than one line to appear, you're going to have to make more than one of that object.

Comment: @KurtRevis I mean, is there an easier way of doing something like this?

Comment: @KurtRevis also self is a class `Line` which has the superclass of `CAShapeLayer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is replacing the `CAShapeLayer`'s path each time you do an animation, so for each "line" that you animate in, you lose the past lines.

To show multiple lines, you could either:

1. Add multiple subpaths to the `CAShapeLayer`'s path, one for each line, using the method [`UIBezierPath.appendPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/appendPath:).
2. Use multiple `CAShapeLayer`s, one for each line.

Here's alternative #1, which is a smaller change from your current code.  This is a self-contained example that you can add into a new iOS project in a view controller called `ViewController`.

```
import UIKit

class MyShapeLayer: CAShapeLayer {
    var animationTime: NSTimeInterval = 0.75

    func repeatThis() {
        // Keep track of the path so far
        var runningPath = UIBezierPath()

        for x in 1...10 {
            let time = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), Int64(x) * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
            dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                // We will add a rectangular subpath onto runningPath.
                // It will be animated starting with:
                let topLineStartPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: x * 10, width: 1, height: 10))
                // and ending with:
                let topLineEndPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: x * 10, width: Int(self.bounds.width), height: 10))

                // Copy the running path, and add the starting and ending subpaths onto it
                let fullStartPath = runningPath.copy() as! UIBezierPath
                fullStartPath.appendPath(topLineStartPath)
                let fullEndPath = runningPath.copy() as! UIBezierPath
                fullEndPath.appendPath(topLineEndPath)

                // Animate from fullStartPath to fullEndPath
                let expAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
                expAnimation.fromValue = fullStartPath.CGPath
                expAnimation.toValue = fullEndPath.CGPath
                expAnimation.duration = self.animationTime
                expAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
                expAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false
                self.addAnimation(expAnimation, forKey: nil)
                print(x)

                // The next time through the loop, add on to this iteration's ending path
                runningPath = fullEndPath
            }
        }
    }
}

class MyView: UIView {
    override class func layerClass() -> AnyClass {
        return MyShapeLayer.self
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        self.view = MyView()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if let myShapeLayer = self.view.layer as? MyShapeLayer {
            myShapeLayer.repeatThis()
        }
    }
}
```

And the result:

[image: Animated GIF of the resulting animation]

Here's a way to do alternative #2. I made the animationTime longer so you can see that the animations for each line can overlap.

```
class LineAtATimeView: UIView {
    var animationTime = 1.25    // longer duration so line animations overlap

    func repeatAddingLines() {
        for x in 1...10 {
            let time = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), Int64(x) * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
            dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                let newLayer = CAShapeLayer()
                newLayer.frame = self.bounds
                self.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)

                let topLineStartPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: x * 10, width: 1, height: 10))
                let topLineEndPath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: x * 10, width: Int(self.bounds.width), height: 10))

                let expAnimation: CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
                expAnimation.fromValue = topLineStartPath.CGPath
                expAnimation.toValue = topLineEndPath.CGPath
                expAnimation.duration = self.animationTime
                expAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
                expAnimation.removedOnCompletion = false
                newLayer.addAnimation(expAnimation, forKey: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        self.view = LineAtATimeView()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if let v = self.view as? LineAtATimeView {
            v.repeatAddingLines()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, that worked thanks :). However when I start a new line before the first one is finished it forces the one that is still animating to finish. Is there a way around this? Thanks again.

Comment: If you need to do that, it would be much easier to use a separate `CAShapeLayer` for each line. Then each line needs only a single animation on it, and they are all independent, so it won't matter if some of them are animating at the same time. You didn't show the code that's setting up the `CAShapeLayer`, so I didn't try to do that.

Comment: Added code to make an independent layer for each line.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the update. I think you misinterpreted the question, sorry! The issue I'm having is where `dispatch_time` is I have it set to a much smaller number... say 0.25 and when it runs, each time I start a new line it skips the one before it to finish. Does that make sense?

Comment: There are two different times: (1) the animation duration `self.animationTime`, and (2) the difference between the time given to `dispatch_after` each time through the loop. What exactly are your values for each? I think the code in alternative #2 should work in all cases. If it doesn't, ask another question _with code to reproduce the exact problem_ that is [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added the issue to the question. Take a look and thanks again for the continued help

Comment: It's expected that Alternative #1 will have that issue. Alternative #2 will not have that issue, so use Alternative #2.